# chrome addon - automatically refresh pages

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need some advice on a chrome add-on. The goal of the addon is to have the page automatically refresh every 60 seconds. Once or twice the page does indeed update, but after that the addon stops working. When I look into the details of the addon I come across "service worker(inactive)" - I think this might be the problem.

Thank you.

manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "AutoRefresh Extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "description": "Automatická aktualizace stránky",
    "permissions": ["storage", "tabs"],
    "background": {
      "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["https://xyz.xy/*"],
        "js": ["content.js"]
      }
    ]
  }
```

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function () {
  console.log("AutoRefresh Extension installed");

  
  chrome.storage.sync.set({ refreshInterval: 60 }); 

  
  startAutoRefresh();
});

chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(function () {
  console.log("AutoRefresh Extension started");
  startAutoRefresh();
});

function startAutoRefresh() {
  chrome.storage.sync.get(["refreshInterval"], function (result) {
    const interval = result.refreshInterval || 60;

    
    setInterval(function () {
      
      chrome.tabs.query({}, function (tabs) {
        tabs.forEach(function (tab) {
          if (tab.url && tab.url.startsWith("https://xyz.xy/")) {       
            chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, { url: tab.url }, function () {              
            });
          } else {
            console.warn("Tab URL doesn't match the specified pattern");
          }
        });
      });
    }, interval * 1000);
  });
}
```

Zkousel jsem zmenit casovy interval napriklad na 10s a to vypada ze funguje, ale kdyz nastavim 60s tak doplnek prestane fungovat.

Comment: Use chrome.alarms instead of setInterval.